# How to Sum up Debit Fee entry based on unique ticket #

Tags: excel, excel-formula

INPUT

```
Debit   Date    Ticket #    Sum Name
-1.0    9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
1.0     9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
1.0     9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
1.0     9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
```

I need this OUTPUT (see below), Sum as 2.0 based on same ticket number and same name and Sum of all previous debit fees.

**How to calculate -1.0+1.0+1.0+1.0 for same ticket+same Name and produce 2.0 in Sum Column?**

```
Debit   Date    Ticket # Sum    Name
-1.0    9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
1.0     9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
1.0     9-Nov   12345           SMITH/I
1.0     9-Nov   12345      2.0  SMITH/I
```

Answer (score 0):

Please understand the formula below, to be entered in cell D2 of your example and copied down (presuming that your sample data start in A1 with captions in row 1).

=SUMIFS($A$2:$A2,$C$2:$C2,$C2,$E$2:$E2,$E2)

`$A$2:$A2` specifies a single cell. But as you copy this formula down the range expands from A2 to the current row of the formula, like A2:A3, A2:A4 etc. Same for the columns C and E.

Because of this method of summing, it is impossible to have blank cells for previous totals as you show in your desired result where totals are suppressed in rows 2:4. The formulas in these rows have no way of knowing if the same combination of Ticker and Name will recur again further down.

Now, logically, if this difference is of importance to you the task isn't to draw the total but to find the ***last*** total. One would have to first count the number of recurrences of the combination in the entire worksheet and then apply the above formula only for the last one. In other words, the same above formula would still do the work but embedded in another one which you didn't ask for.